# Passing url with onclick to flowplayer

Tags: jquery, html, flowplayer

I have a table that gets built up from a database.  That loops through to create a row:

```
<tr >
   <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_url"]; ?>');">
    <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["camera_name"]; ?> 
   </td>
   <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_url"]; ?>');">
    <?php echo setlocalTime($result_videos[$i]["video_datetime"]); ?> 
   </td>
....
</tr>
```

When a user clicks on a row in the table it sends it to the `DoNav` function to launch flowplayer:
    var js = jQuery.noConflict();
    function DoNav(theUrl)
    { 
    //flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", theUrl);
    var mydiv = js("#player");
    var $myhref = js("");
    mydiv.append($myhref);
    }

I try to build the player as a href.  It must be an href and not like the commented line (which I had before, which works but won't help for iOS support)

Here is the div I used before and the final call to flowplayer in the body:

```
<div id="player" style="display:block;width:320px;height:240px;background-image:url(images/videoPlaceHolder01.JPG)"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">
flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf");
</script>
```

Clicking rows does nothing anymore and I see no errors.  Pretty sure I'm mixing up the behavior with div and href for flowplayer which is not right. In fact I'm mixing too many things here and wondering if there is an easier way to create an onclick event to then launch flowplayer before I continue on this crazy path.  Note I do want to keep the splash image.

Comment: Do you have an example anywhere?

Comment: Looks like you're appending an empty anchor tag instead of wrapping the anchor tag around your image. Also, what's up with the js(...) stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/SAZd4/

To start I store the video url in an html5 data construct. This is `data-videourl`. You can then retrieve this value using jQuery's data method. I then monitor the click event of the td to get the url and construct a jQuery link object that contains the necessary parameters. Finally you have to instantiate the player using the flowplayer code.

```
<table>
    <tr >
       <td class="video" data-videourl="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv">Video X</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
$('td.video').click(function() {
    //get video url from data-videourl html5 param
    var videourl = $(this).data('videourl');

    //create a link tag to contain the video
    var $video = $('<a />', {
        href: videourl,
        id: 'player'
    });

    //append link to page
    $('body').append($video);

    //instantiate flowplayer on new video object
    flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
        clip: {

            // these two configuration variables does the trick
            autoPlay: true,
            autoBuffering: true // <- do not place a comma here  
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hrmm, the fiddle works great. But in my code I get: `$("td.video") is null`. Not sure where the difference may be. I do have multiple td elements in the tr but I added that to your fiddle and that still works fine.  The only other thing is that this table is dynamic and is built from a loop. Don't know if that is the difference?

Comment: @TomPepernic - do your td's have the class 'video' on them? That selector means, whenever a `td` with `class=video` is clicked, do this.

Comment: yes, I copied exactly what you have. I tried just your code separately and I get the same thing. So must be something with my configuration?

Comment: You have included jQuery on the page and this js call is after it has loaded? You are executing the jQuery code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Well progress at least. Now flowplayer chokes on me with several errors: `[ERROR] time 15:37:32.58 :: org.flowplayer.view::PluginLoader : onIoError http://mydomain.com/flowplayer/flowplayer.controls-3.2.5.swf
http://mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=39
Line 0` and many others such as not finding the stream

Comment: does it really say 'mydomain.com' or did you substitute that in?

Comment: Did you change my code to point to 3.2.5 swf instead of 3.5.7?

Comment: This is frustrating, I've just tried all your code in the fiddle verbatim and it still doesn't work.  Doesn't make sense when the fiddle does.

Comment: Can you post a link to your site? Then I can figure it out.

Comment: I'd appreciate that. But it is a development site, provide me your email address or email me: azukich@sympatico.ca and I'll set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could be the problem but you missed the double quotes at this line:

```
var $myhref = js("<a href=" + theUrl + " id=player></a>");
```

You should fix as follows:

```
var $myhref = js("<a href=\"" + theUrl + "\" id=\"player\"></a>");
```